# How to query SQL on date AND time

Tags: mysql, sql

My current table looks like this - Table is called "S"

```
DJ     DATE
----   ------
test   yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss
```

I've worked up to the below SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `S` 
WHERE  `DATE` =  '2017-02-27 17:00:00'
ORDER BY  `S`.`DATE` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Rather than having the set date and time though I would like to query based on the current date AND time. I'm using datetime type structure.

All I'm looking to do is query the current datetime to get the current name from the DJ row

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `now()` function to get the current datetime.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `S` 
WHERE  `DATE` =  now()
ORDER BY  `S`.`DATE` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

If you want to get result for today's *date*, you can use curdate and date function

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `S` 
WHERE  date(`DATE`) =  curdate()
ORDER BY  `S`.`DATE` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: In case OP is wondering to get zero results, this will only work if there's an entry for the exact second the query is run

Comment: Yes I know, your answer answers the question. It will just be OP's next question... I guess... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot to include that it's based on a DJ's 2 hour time slot, so "test" would start at 17:00. What happens when it's passed 17:00 and they're in the second hour?

Comment: @GurV - Thanks for the response, this worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

With mysql, you can use the [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) function.

```
SELECT *
FROM S
WHERE DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER BY S.DATE DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select s.*
from s
where date(date) = CURDATE() and
      hour(date) = hour(NOW())
order s.date` DESC 
limit 0, 1;
```